# Django: Automatically invalidate cache when data changes via Admin panel?

Tags: django, caching

On a roll with Django questions today.

The caching framework looks pretty awesome and I'd like to use it sitewide. Rather than set an explicit expiry time for my views, I'd prefer to cache them indefinitely and only invalidate/delete the cache when the content changes. Dream scenario, right?

Is there some way to hook into Django's automatic admin so that when a CRUD operation happens, the relevant cache gets deleted? I expect I'd have to somehow tell the admin panel which model should invalidate which class, but in principle, is this possible? Some kind of callback I can add? Any alternatives?

thanks!
Matt

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two part answer:

1. Clear cache on a CRUD event? Easy as pie — use [Django signals](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/).
2. Clear *only* the relevant parts of the cache? This is a genuinely hard problem. On the surface it may look straightforward, but the dependencies can be very difficult to discern for all but the most trivial cases.

We sort of solved part 2 by extending the django caching code to embed object class/id info into the name, and then caching at a sub-page level. On a CRUD event we could do a simple regexp through the cached item names and prune as needed.

All in all, I think it was yet another case of [Premature Optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) and it's not at all clear that it made any difference. Next time I'll wait until there is a proven, measurable performance problem before doing something like this.

Comment: Interesting, thank you for the links. You may be right - I suspect the slowness I'm seeing in page rendering could be my ignorance of how Django's operating, SQL wise, under the hood. I'm going to revisit the docs for ManyToMany and figure out if I could be doing it better. I have a feeling I'm running queries in `n+1` amounts in certain places.

Comment: Addendum to the above: just installed django_debug_toolbar: my homepage is currently making 409 queries. Time to read up on optimising ManyToMany...